# How to solve cookie sqlite error 1555? (Python & Selenium)

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I have this code that opens a website, logs in and then goes to directed link. It worked well by itself but I am running multiple instances of these. This I copy and paste the code up to 20 times in it, so it can open 20 of them.

It starts opening them and closes, checking the CMD I then get the below.

But I keep getting the cook sqlite error 1555 code like this.

```
[11136:14348:0216/175236.148:ERROR:connection.cc(1947)] Cookie sqlite error 1555, errno 0: UNIQUE constraint failed: cookies.creation_utc, sql: INSERT INTO cookies (creation_utc, host_key, name, value, encrypted_value, path, expires_utc, secure, httponly, firstpartyonly, last_access_utc, has_expires, persistent, priority) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Also it says this

```
124:60160:1022/202621.325:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(237)] Failed to
create shader cache entry: -2
```

I am not sure if this an issue because it's opening the same default chrome profile for each one. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Is each instance writing to the same sqlite database? If so, the first instance that encounters a collision with the file already open will fail. See https://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately I'm having the same issue with chromedriver 2.35 on chrome 65. It just appeared in the last week, though perhaps an upgrade to chromedriver 2.37 will fix this.

The odd part is, I'm only opening one driver in this case (and disposing it correctly), and it still occurs. So I expect this is a bug in chromedriver that's popping up. Which versions of chromedriver/chrome are you running?

Comment: Same problem with Protractor (on Angular platform) that uses Selenium under the hood. Similarly, the issue appeared last week! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49659964/protractor-tests-broke-with-no-apparent-reason-timed-out-waiting-for-asynchron